# KOMA-script section heading ragged left on verso pages

Tags: horizontal-alignment, sectioning, koma-script

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\section{Foo}

\blindtext

\clearpage

\section{Bar}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

I'd like to have the section headings ragged left (i.e. toward the inner margin) on verso (even) pages. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work fine

```
\renewcommand*{\raggedsection}{\Ifthispageodd{}{\raggedleft}}
```